# What is `gopher` and is it still used?

Tags: internet, network-protocols

Reading some rather old computer books, I have seen the `gopher` protocol mentioned frequently.
What is it used for? And, is it still used today?

Comment: The [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gopher_(protocol)) covers this reasonably well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gopher was a text based protocol that was used on the internet on the early days. Unlike http and the web as we know it, sites were structured, and accessed through a hierarchical menu.It was, in essence the predecessor of HTTP, and the web

Currently gopher is a historical curiosity, but many major browsers had support for it at one point, but currently you'd either need a separate client or a plugin to access it. It hasn't really aged as gracefully as irc or usenet did, and there's very few gopher servers in use right now.

Comment: Great answer (+1)!  I remember using Opera a few years ago to access a Gopher server (so it may be one of the last), but I don't know if the current version still has support for it.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia is going to be [the best answer](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gopher_%28protocol%29) to this I think, but here's a quick summary.

Gopher is another information-dissemination protocol that came out in the early 90s, like HTTP. It's text-based, and designed to provide structured, hierarchical information quickly and easily. It's not used much today, it's believed there are less than 200 gopher servers running on the internet.